# Does compileOnly work with Android Native Module?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, react-native

I need a help for android native module. Does `compileOnly` dependency works in Native module.

Let's say I have two native SDKs `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging` and `com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display` and one react native plugin `firebase-react-native`

In 1 plugin only i want to expose public APIs for both native SDKs but I want to add it as optional dependency(compileOnly) so If few Apps don't want to use `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging` then they can omit it in App's gradle file.

In Android world it works easily. But in RN when i add one of them as `comipleOnly` then it throws `ClassNotFoundException` during runtime.

How do I achieve optional SDK support for Apps so that extra SDK size does not introduce without creating 2 seprate RN plugins?

Thanks